# How to pass a secret from a forked github repo to source repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I have forked a public GitHub repository to create a fork repo.

The PR build in the source repo is created using GitHub Actions, and looks like:

```
name: "Continuous Integration"

env:
  GH_OAUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_OAUTH_TOKEN }}

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "develop"
      - "staging"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "develop"
      - "staging"

jobs:
  ...
```

The source repo do not have the secret `GH_OAUTH_TOKEN`, and expect it to be created in my forked repo, and then supplied to their workflow.

So I created this secret in my forked repo.

But when I created a PR and then run the above workflow (that runs in source repo), it doesn't have `GH_OAUTH_TOKEN` secret available. It has only the secrets from source repo.

I have gone through my GitHub settings, but couldn't find a setting to enable this.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a protection to not allow people to simply exfiltrate all your secrets by submitting a pull-request](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/). A malicious person could propose a change to the workflow that lists every secret and sends it to an S3 bucket for example.

There is a different trigger called `on: pull_request_target` which will have access to the secrets. It will always run the workflow on the base branch instead of the pull-request branch and will require an explicit checkout command to be added to the workflow to check out the changed code.

```
# ⚠️ INSECURE. Provided as an example only.
on:
  pull_request_target

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

> **⚠️ This is a dangerous trigger!** - [Read the blogpost about PWN request carefully as it explains many of the caveats surrounding these scenarios](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/). It can be safe in certain cases, but requires you fully understand what you're doing.

For additional security you can enable explicit approvals to run pull request workflows in your repository settings. This will allow you to carefully inspect the changes prior to kicking off the workflow.

[image]

[For private repos there is a setting that will allow secrets to be exposed, but only to private forks](https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/).

[image]

Comment: Can a malicious actor get secrets of a source repo (by using a forked repo) assuming it's `pull_request` and not `pull_request_target`, assuming the actor is not a first time contributor to the source repo?

Comment: No, since secrets aren't populated for public repo PR workflows using `pull_request`.