# How to enable a PR originating from a forked repo to cause a GitHub workflow to push to a branch (gh-pages) in the original repo?

Tags: github, permissions, fork, push, workflow

I'm admin for a source repo for an Antora-based documentation site. I have a workflow that, when a PR is created or upon a push to the PR, builds the site and pushes it to the `gh-pages` branch, so you can see what the site looks like with the changes from the PR, before merging it to `main`. This works fine so long as contributions are made by someone with `write` access to the repo.

But when someone submits a PR from a fork of the repo, the workflow builds the site just fine, but it fails to commit to the `gh-pages` branch because the fork doesn't have the correct permissions. Here's the error message from the GitHub action log:

```
...
Commit successful. Pushing changes.
remote: Permission to example-org/example-docs.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/example-org/example-docs/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

A failed workflow, and the code of the workflow file, is here: https://github.com/starknet-io/starknet-docs/actions/runs/7885678276/workflow

We thought we had a fix with this PR:
https://github.com/starknet-io/starknet-docs/pull/1097/files

But this introduced a security vulnerability that enabled a user to view the repo's secrets.

This issue vulnerability issue is mentioned here: [How to pass a secret from a forked github repo to source repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76975408/how-to-pass-a-secret-from-a-forked-github-repo-to-source-repo)